# Is Solr a Good Solution for the Problem Described Below?

Tags: php, apache, drupal, lucene, solr

I am volunteering for a non-profit and the CEO would like an application that stores resumes of University professors. The resumes are to be searchable so that possible employers can find them. The resumes could be in a variety of formats, including pdf or Word.

The Web site is currently based on Joomla!, but may move to Drupal. In either case, the developers are familiar with PHP. I am familiar with PHP as well as Java.

What is the best architecture for this application? I am considering:

1. Installing either the Java or PHP version of SOLR and linking to it
   through PHP, using the PHP Solr extension.
2. Using the PHP version of Lucene directly and bypassing Solr.
3. Use the Search Lucene API Drupal extension, which provides Solr-like functionality.

If I have left any possibilities out, please let me know.

Also, I couldn't find a good book on Solr on Amazon. There is a good one on Lucene, though (the In Action series). Unfortunately, it only briefly mentions Solr. Is it worthwhile reading a good book on Lucene in order to understand how to use Solr better, or would I be wasting my time/money? I also couldn't find any good books on Solr...but maybe you can recommend one.

Comment: "Is it worthwhile reading a good book on Lucene in order to..."? No, I just used the Solr tutorials, never touched a lucene article. I used the Solr wiki and where I was stuck, I used the free ebook "Solr 1.4 Enterprise Search Server" from Lucid Imagination. That book is incomplete in places, but it's ..ahem.. action-oriented.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Solr is a good match:

- Solr comes out of the box with a feature called [ExtractingRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler), which lets you easily index Word, PDF and other proprietary formats.
- Solr is highly configurable when it comes to full-text searching, you'll probably get better results than with MySQL full-text.
- Solr is fast. MySQL full-text, [not so much](http://entropytc.com/importing-a-mysql-database-into-apache-solr/).
- Solr enables [faceted navigation](http://www.lucidimagination.com/devzone/technical-articles/faceted-search-solr).
- There are two Joomla integration modules for Solr ([JSolr](http://www.wijiti.com/projects/jsolr), [TNR ESearch](http://www.solrhq.com/solrhq-for-cms/joomla-extension-for-solr-and-solrhq/)) and [one for Drupal](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr).

Choosing Solr is not just about its performance, it's also about its features and flexibility.

About Solr books, see:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343671/book-recomendation-for-solr
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821470/book-about-solr-for-version-3-x

Books about Lucene will help you understand how text is processed under the hood, which may come in handy if you have to fine-tune text analysis, however I'd recommend starting with a book about Solr.

Comment: If I use Solr to index and search these binary documents, will it store them in the file system or in a MySQL database?

Comment: @Sam: you can store the files wherever you want, it's orthogonal to Solr.

Answer (score 0):

Solr is a great option however based upon your requirement i suggest you go with Sphinx Search engine which has an excellent extremely well documented PHP API. Note that I love Solr for some of its great features however Solr cant beat Sphinx with respect to Indexing Algorithms (i.e Index Time and Index Size on the disk).

There is an excellent book available on Solr - Solr 1.4 Enterprise Search Server [PACKT PUBLISHING]. You can also go through IBM Developer works great article on Solr. Search for "Searching Smart with Solr IBM Developerworks " on Google.

PS: Still I feel Sphinx would be the best choice for you.

Comment: Can Solr work with a NoSQL database? What are the advantages of a NoSQL database for this application and in general? What NoSQL database would you recommend?

Comment: I am sorry. Actually you don't really require a NoSQL database, I misunderstood your question a bit. Please try out Sphinx, it will really be well suited for your application (It will take very little time to start indexing and searching with Sphinx).

Answer (score -1):

Based on what you have explained, no Solr is not a good match.

You would be more than capable of being able to do fulltext searching through mysql if you needed. The fact that you mention Joomla and Drupal obviously point to that as being the RDMS that you are using.

If I were to start this project from afresh, I would probably use some noSQL engine, something like MongoDB to create my Resume Documents. [www.mongodb.com](http://www.mongodb.org/)

That is how I would **persist** my data.

If it then comes to wanting to search the documents, I would only consider using Solr if I expect to have thousands of tens of thousands of searchs a day. It really doesn't require the effort of implementing a Solr application if you only expect 100-1000 searches a day.

And, to answer you book question on Solr, the book which I own and would recommend, is http://www.packtpub.com/solr-1-4-enterprise-search-server/book but I'm sure you could probably find something a little more recent. I bought that like 18-24 months ago.

You first would want to store the details of each person... so

Comment: And how are you proposing he get MySQL to index the PDFs and DOCs? Solr is hardly that hard to set up, especially with the Drupal/Joomla/etc. integrations built-in.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot that it is **impossible** to read PDFs and .docs in anything but Solr. </sarcasm>

Comment: It's certainly not impossible, but it's already built into Solr. You talk about the "effort of implementing a Solr application" (it took me about 45 minutes to set up Solr for Drupal) while glossing over the effort of indexing PDFs and DOCs in MySQL.

Comment: It just so happens that I am starting this project from scratch--but why use NoSQL/MongoDB?

Comment: Well, my reasoning was that when you are storing Documents, such as CV information, if you wanted to allow users to create their resumes online, then mongodb would be aptly suited for this. That's because it would be extremely hard to model a CV before hand. If you were to do it via mysql, you might be tempted to use a EAV approach for all of their fields, qualifications etc. Whereas, mongodb you could create all of your fields.